Deploy angular application on Apache Tomcat 404
I tried to deploy my Angular application to Apache Tomcat as a war file.
I try to do it the following way, but I face a 404 error. Here are the steps for how I do it:

I added one line of code to the angular.json file: 
"baseHref": "/my-angular-app/"


In the root folder, I ran the following command:
ng build --configuration production --base-href=/my-angular-app/

Run the following command to create a war file:
jar -cvf my-angular-app.war *

After that, I pasted the war to the wars folder(D:\apis-distribution-3.8.0-dev (1)\APISdev\engine\server\apache-tomcat-9.0.75)

Restart the server.

Still see the same error.


I tried several ways to handle it but still got the same error.

I believe you just want to take the "dist" or "build" folder whatever is output from the ng build command (based on the angular.json configuration) is what you would want bundled in the WAR file to be deployed, if you are just bundling the entire project you're including all the source and potentially dependencies in the WAR that are unnecessary for the deployed/production app to run.
Something like:
jar -cvf my-angular-app.war dist/*
